# xlToRight fills all the way Right

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to fill in cell color starting from certain column number to the last column, therefore I've used

```
    Set colour_range = Range(Cells(1, colnum).Offset(0, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))
colour_range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
```

Everything works fine, however the interior.color does not stop at the last not empty cell (like I am using ctrl+right or ctrl+shift+right) but goes all the way with filling till the last column (column XFD).

Any suggestion show to overcome that? Its just a cosmetic issue but it keeps bothering me

Answer (score 1):

Please, change:

```
 Set colour_range = Range(Cells(1, colnum).Offset(0, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))
```

with:

```
 Set colour_range = Range(Cells(1, colnum).Offset(0, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
```

`Cells(1, Columns.Count)` means the last cell on the first row.

`xlToRight` extends the range up to the last cell to the right. If nothing (else) exists, it stays to the last one...

But `xlToLeft` goes from the last existing column (`Columns.Count`) to the left until the last existing one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more data to the right of the relevant data (e.g. another table), then if your row is contiguous (has no empty cells), you can use...

```
Option Explicit

Sub decorateFirstRow()
    
    Const ColNum As Long = 2
    Dim colour_range As Range
    
    Set colour_range = Range(Cells(1, ColNum).Offset(0, 1), _
                             Cells(1, ColNum).Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight))
    colour_range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)

End Sub
```

...mimicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>. If it is the last column of the worksheet, then rather use FaneDuru's solution.

Answer (score 0):

`xlToRight` means you want to use the formula to the very end of right

`Columns.Count` sets you at the very last available column, therefore `xlToLeft` is proper idea - from last available column all the way to the left (stops at the column chosen at `colnum` parameter)

Hope it helps you to understand what's going on behind code